# PostgreSQL database with ~10,000 boolean states per row

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how design this particular database. It has the following features:

- Expected 3 million+ rows corresponding to 'users';
- Each 'user' has associated with them ~10,000 unique boolean states;
- These states are sparse in nature, and additional states will be added in the future, and likely shouldn't be stored in an ordered list;
- The states will be updated frequently, at a rate of about 20 in the span of 2 hours, every 24 hours, on average per active 'user';

The obvious design is to have a lookup table between the users and the states, but I'm concerned this will not be fast enough, when looking up states per user, with an expected 5 billion+ rows in the lookup table.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: My current best idea for a solution is storing a binary stream per user, and mapping the individual bits of the stream to the individual states. Regarding this, I forgot to include an important detail: I do not need to lookup users based on their states very frequently at all. It isn't ideal or very scalable for when I do need those lookups more frequently, though.

Comment: If you are concerned about the speed of the obvious design, you need to create som test data and check that, while making sure the indexes you create are relevant for the queries. You need to do that for any non-obvious solutions too, they could perform even much worse than the obvious design.

Comment: If I understand you, a user's record will undergo ~20 updates during a 2 hour period, then nothing until the next day? Do you expect all users to be updated within the same 2 hour window? Or spread out evenly throughout a 24 hour period? And you occasionally need to find users with a given state set?

Comment: @AdamBenson Yes that is correct. And yes, spread out over a 24 hour period. The occasional searches of all users with a given state would be for analytics, which don't need to be 'live'.

Comment: @nos Thank you for you comment, you're right in that this is something that warrants testing!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a relation between 2 tables

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | username                                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | bl-ro                                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | darkmukke                                 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

and then a relation for the bools

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | fk_user | bool                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | true                            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1       | false                           |
--------------------------------------------------
```